# Does cdh5.1.2 support Parquet file format

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, parquet, file-format

Does Cloudera 5.1.2 support Parquet fileformat ..

Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.2

Do we have some compatibility on cloudera site

Comment: Parquet was developed by Cloudera (and Twitter). You can use/install `parquet-tools` on Unix systems.

Comment: @philantrovert i got that now , I was more toward if it supports parquet and it does there is no extra package needed to write the parquet files in  this version of hadoop

Comment: @philantrovert parquet-tools how does it work , can i install same on cloudera and is it needed , as of now to read the files i use spark-sql

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In the release notes for CDH5.1, it mentions:

> Apache Hive
>
> - Permission inheritance fixes
> - Support for decimal computation, and for reading and writing decimal-format data from and to Parquet and Avro

and under "Cloudera Search":

> - Support for the Parquet file format is included with this version of Kite 0.10.0.

so it's supported.

Also under the CDH repository for CDH5.1.2 (RedHat 6.x) you'll see the following package:

> parquet-1.2.5+cdh5.1.2+136-1.cdh5.1.2.p0.2.el6.noarch.rpm   2014-08-27 22:40    10M

So parquet release 1.2.5 was supported with CDH5.1.2.

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Release-Notes/cdh5rn_new_in_510.html
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/5.1.2/RPMS/noarch/

Comment: Thanks , We have started writing the parquet files in same version of hadoop